# how to remove index controller only from url in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, router

In the project I have many controllers,such as Index,Member,Download.

now I want to make the url like www.test.com/index/product to www.test.com/product

but don't want change url www.test.com/member/signup to www.test.com/signup

PS:I added 4 lines in the application.ini

```
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

That has dogged me for many days, hope someone can point out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't actually have a product controller, you can add this:

```
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.route = "product/"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.chains.index.defaults.action = "product"
```

and now ***www.test.com/index/product*** and ***www.test.com/product*** will both work and end up at the same place.

Comment: ah,sorry I means action ,Thank you for your answer,it works for me,btw is there a way to make multiple actions under index controller and then remove index from the URL with only one router?
e.g.
www.test.com/index/product to www.test.com/product 
www.test.com/index/test to www.test.com/test etc...

Comment: Can we remove index from controller for all the actions from index controller